# Re-run application in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When launching a Java application in Eclipse its output goes to the console view. I can stop the application from there, but I can't relaunch it as it happens in Idea.

Is there a command/option/plugin for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ctrl+F11 -> Run last launched

F11 -> Debug last launched

Comment: There is a preference for F11: Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching.
Under Launch Operation there is a choice between 'Always launch the previously launched application' and 'Launch the selected resource or active editor'.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl + F11 (Run lasted launched)