# How to relaunch the last m2eclipse launch

Tags: maven, m2eclipse

My question is very close of this one => [Re-run application in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944306/re-run-application-in-eclipse)

But Ctrl+F11 doesn't relaunch a maven command launch through m2eclipse, for example it launch for now, testng.